# Reading a text file (with integers) row by row and storing each row as a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, text

I'm working on graph theory problems and using the adjacency list implementation. I have long text files which represent the adjacency list of graphs with N>100 vertices.

The text files are written in the following manner:

1 2 3

2 3 1

3 2

This will represent a graph of three vertices. The first number is the vertex, and the rest of the numbers in that row represent the adjacent vertices.

I have currently declared the adjacency list as

```
vector<vector<int> > adjList(N);
```

and my goal is to copy each row into each element of adjList.

I've read files using ifstream before, but these files were only to copy massive data sets into an array and I feel this problem is different.

How can I do this?

my current code looks like this:

```
ifstream inFile;
int N=200;
vector<vector<int> > adj(N);

inFile.open("/Users/davidvillarreal/Desktop/aaa.txt");
cout << "opened " << endl;
if (inFile.fail()) {
    cerr << "error encountered" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: So you've opened the file... Are you familiar with `getline` and `stringstream`?

Comment: I was reading about it right now, but decided it wouldnt work. Was I wrong? How exactly would it work here?

Comment: @DavidV *but decided it wouldnt work* -- And how did you come to that decision?

Comment: Try it. First try reading the whole file using `getline`, without doing anything with the numbers themselves. Then take a single line of text like "1 2 3" and try parsing it my means of `stringstream`. Once you have both those things working perfectly, combine them.

Comment: Will this method still work if i'm going to be working with integers and not strings?

Comment: In addition, why did you assume a size of 200 for your vector size?  A vector is dynamic -- it can grow as you read.  Just start it out as empty.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've only been able to use push_back when referring to the first index in my vector (this adds elements to the second index). Writing adj.push_back(3) for example, hasnt worked (thats why I've been specifying the exact size for the first index in my vector). Perhaps I'm wrong though...

Comment: @DavidV -- Yes, you're wrong.  A vector's size never needs to be predetermined if you're going to add items to it dynamically.  It doesn't make sense to think otherwise since a vector is designed to be able to grow in size dynamically.  In your case, that item happens to be a `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small example, should show one way of doing this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
//...
int main()
{
    // use a typedef to simplify things a bit 
    typedef std::vector<int> Int1D;
    typedef std::vector<Int1D> Int2D;

    // declare the adjacency list
    Int2D adjList;

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile;
    //...
    //..assume that infile has been opened successfully
    //...
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
       // use a string stream to help parse the ints
       std::istringstream strm(line);
       int n;

       // add an empty row
       adjList.push_back(Int1D());

       // now fill in the last row we added by reading in the ints
       while (strm >> n)
          adjList.back().push_back(n);
    }

    // output results
    for (size_t i = 0; i < adjList.size(); ++i)
    {
       std::copy(adjList[i].begin(), adjList[i].end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
       std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/m4pIQB)

Note that we have two loops -- the "read" loop, and the loop to add each `int` to the last added vector to the `adjList`. The usage of `vector::back()` gives us a reference to the last vector added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do like this.. if the file format is strictly one space and an integer .... and at the end new line..

```
vector<int> v;
vector<vector<int>> vv;
int i;
char c = ' ' ;
//repeat next until the eof
while(c != '\n') {
    f >> skipws >> i;
    v.push_back(i);
    f >> noskipws >> c;
}
vv.push_back(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

   std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
   std::ifstream file("data.txt");
   std::string line;

   if ( file ) {
       while(std::getline(file, line)) {
          std::stringstream sline(line);
          data.push_back(std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>( sline ), std::istream_iterator<int>() ));
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```